# WCF CallBack works on same machine, but does not work over network

Tags: wcf, callback

I have tried to implement WCF callback using WSDualHttpBinding. The service is hosted on IIS 7.

When I created a sample client for the service on the same machine as the host, it works fine. But when I ran the same client from a different system on the network I get timeout exception

Server stack trace:at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.ThrowTimeoutException()at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableRequestor.Request(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableSession.Open(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

The CallbackContract look as follows:

```
 public interface IMyServiceCallBack
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Notify();
}
```

I have also specified

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
```

The app.config on Client is as follows:

```
 <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_Callback" closeTimeout="00:01:00"                         clientBaseAddress="http://10.1.3.199:8002/myServiceHost/myService.svc/Endpoint"
                     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                     maxBufferPoolSize="97108864" maxReceivedMessageSize="97108864"
                     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="97108864" maxArrayLength="97108864"
                  maxBytesPerRead="97108864" maxNameTableCharCount="97108864" />              
              <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
          </wsDualHttpBinding>
<client>
 <endpoint address="http://10.1.3.199/myServiceHost/myService.svc/Endpoint"
                binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_Callback"
                contract="myService.ServiceContract" name="WSDualHttpBinding_Callback" />
</client>
```

What am I MISSING!!!

Answer (score 2):

`WSDualHttpBinding` will only work if both port 80 is reachable by the server *and the client*. Yes, that means the server will attempt to open a TCP connection back to your client. Over the internet `WSDualHttpBinding` is basically useless as most users sit behind routers which do not route the connection back from the server to the client.

**If you're on the same network (like you said) then you need to ensure port 80 (or whatever port you use) is allowed by the firewall on the client machine.**

An alternative is to use `NetTcpBinding` which opens a single *outgoing* tcp connection allowing duplex communucation. This is a good alternative if your clients and server are always on the same network.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59677/wsdualhttpbinding-for-duplex-callbacks) post for more info on WSDualHttpBinding

Comment: I would really like to get wsDualHttpBinding working. The firewall is turned off. I don't believe it is a firewall issue. What other things should I look at?

Comment: not sure, you might need to use wireshark to see whats going on. also, is the client able to reach the server? (ie put a log statement on the server to see if that way works)